# Is perl gmtime function thread safe

Tags: multithreading, perl

Don't have a specific issue here. We have some log processing which is using `gmtime` to output data from a time_t style timestamp. e.g.

```
print POSIX::strftime( '%Y-%m-%d-%T', gmtime($rec[$time_field]) )
```

The process is written in perl (5.16.3 with ithreads) and is using multiple threads. It seems to be working, but my concern is whether the gmtime function is thread safe. I know its not in C, just wondering if anyone has experience with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's implemented by [`Perl_gmtime64_r`](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob?f=time64.c), which is a 64-bit version of re-entrant (thread-safe) `gmtime_r`.